# Remote jobs: why is app in the app store so important?

Tags: interviewing, remote-work

I'm a iOS developer, when I apply for local companies, the emphasis of the interviews are on investigating my knowledge and my skills. So that, I would say, most important criteria to choose me iare job interview, CV and my apps in app store.

However when I apply for remote jobs, I noticed that having an app in the app store is quite important. I would say almost a must, even if my CV is quite good, as I worked with several well known companies worldwide.

Why do you think is that? Is because competition is quite fierce for remote jobs applications? Or is because they feel more reassured if I've personally published one my app, rather than just worked on companies app?

thank you

Answer (score 3):

I can only assume, that companies that hiring people to work remotely doesn't care where did you work before, but what you actually can do.

I think they don't want to waste time and call each company you've worked with, and ask how were you performing - checking out your apps is easier/faster in my opinion.

I'm a remote worker (front-end web) - during my career I've got asked for recommendations / people to call to double-check from my previous work places only once - all other companies wanted to see what I've actually build.

I think that's the specifics of the remote workers - companies doesn't care who you know, but what you know (or what you can do).

Comment: I see your point. However, I don't know how it works where you live, but where I live companies don't usually call each other company... they just inspect what the companies are doing and then they ask what have you done there. I mean... I don't see any difference local/remote for that. You can easily contact a company to ask information about past employee in the same way, with a phone call, or by sending an e-mail.

Comment: I don't think a company here cares about who I know, but only what I know. But an app in the appstore doesn't show that I know more than what I know. Of coruse is better, but then it should be the same local/remote.